# ARM equivalent of x86 Heaven's Gate

Tags: assembly, x86, arm, 32bit-64bit

It's possible to mix 32-bit and 64-bit x86 code in the same process by changing the code segment between `0x23` and `0x33`, like this:

```
BITS 32
; do 32-bit stuff
call 0x33:foo
; do more 32-bit stuff

BITS 64
foo:
; do 64-bit stuff
retf
```

How do I do the same thing on ARM?

Comment: You can't.  To change operation modes, you need to be at EL1 or higher.  There's a procedure for that in the relevant Architecture Reference Manual.

Comment: @fuz If you write that as an answer (and even better, also link to that section of one such manual), I'll accept it.